# Multiple render (or partial in rails app)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am updating a rails app which, on a page, makes a network call to get some data which can take a lot of time depending on the time range.

What I'd like to do is make multiple calls (sequential), with small time ranges, and keep on updating the view as and when I keep on getting the data.

I've read numerous posts, stackoverflow questions but I can't seem to find a solution for this.

I understand that I cannot call render more than once.

What I'd like to know from experts is that whether what I am seeking is even possible in rails?

Comment: Use ActionCable(live update using websockets) with Sidekiq(for background job). You long running job will keep on getting data and action cable will update UI as it receives.

Comment: Thanks, I will read about it.

Answer (score 0):

ActionCable is great but it might be over the top rolling out websocket infrastructure if you don't need two-way communication between your client and your server.

Very high level ideating:

1) Build a function using Javascript Promises (or a library with implicit Promises) that can be called recursively when the request Promise resolves.

2) Define your first 'package' of data needed, render it, and trigger your recursive function.

3) Without knowing too much of the context, I'd say the biggest challenge is to design the mechanism that 'knows' when you have loaded all of the data that you need.

Comment: So, the controller gets some parameters and a time range. What currently happens is one single API call is made to another service which is passed these parameters and the time range. if the range is big then the external call takes a time. I can run a loop by making one call each per day between this time range but I am not sure how to keep on adding data to the page when each of these call finishes.